# Failed installation 18.04.1

Tags: hard-drive

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 64-bit on an apparently healthy **Seagate Pipeline HD (Model ST3320310CS) SATA** HDD.

Each time a dialog box tells me there is an **"apt configuration problem"**: *"An attempt to configure apt to install additional package from the CD* *failed*".

I am then told that the installation has failed. In the case of this Ubuntu installation I've been using a USB key, burnt via Unetbootin. Via this USB key, I can see that many Ubuntu files have been copied on to the HDD, but the installation refuses to complete. I also tried another USB live key, but the result was identical. For both USB keys, the sha256sum checks I did were successful.

I previously tried installing Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 on the same HDD on 2 different 64-bit computers (with both a USB key and DVD) and the message I received was very similar to the one above.

I ran the **hard drive DST short test** from the BIOS and it passed. According to the screenshot for this HDD (taken via the Ubuntu live USB key) [NB AskUbuntu has refused to accept this png image in my post] , the assessment for the HDD is “*ok*”.

I’m totally perplexed why the installation won’t complete; I’ve installed Ubuntu, Lubuntu etc with no problems on many occasions in the past on **used** HDDs.  However, I recently bought this problem HDD from a local dealer and although it didn’t come with any packaging, it looks **unused**. So I’m wondering if I have to format it in some way before trying to install? If so, I’m wondering how to proceed now with all the Ubuntu files that are already copied on to it?

Although I’ve gradually learned how to do some very rudimentary technical things on Ubuntu (like doing the sha256sum check and doing a few commands on Terminal), my know-how is still extremely limited.  So bearing this in mind and that this HDD will only have Ubuntu installed on it (and NOT Windows), I wonder if you suggest that I try to follow the instructions on this Help page to install a new hard disk here?:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

The above instructions are looking extremely daunting to me at the moment! So do you think I might find it easier to look at Seagate’s **“DiscWizard”** software (available online according to the sticker on the HDD) ?

Many thanks in advance for any replies.
[image]

Comment: It seems you have run up against this problem: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/73325-Installation-from-USB-fails-looking-for-nonexistent-CD Try another way to create a USB stick than UNetbootin.

Comment: Thanks Jos, I'll study that link in depth later. I've already tried a DVD with UbuntuMate on it, but it was the same problem. When I get my hands on a different HDD and install Ubuntu on it with the USB stick, this would presumably confirm that the problem is with the HDD and not with the stick?